# Can i use air filter that is one inch smaller

Tags: air-conditioning, furnace, air-quality, air-filter

Currently, i have a 16x25x1 filter in my furnace/ac duct (probably a better term out there).

I am at the local store and they seem to be all sold of all brands of 16x25x1. They do however have an extensive selection of 16x24x1.

Would using the 1 inch smaller be ok or could this be detrimental to my furnace/health? Thank you

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Filters only work if the air has to go through them. The filter has air resistance and a gap doesn't, so if you leave a 1" gap, a disproportionate amount of air will flow through the hole, effectively making the situation even worse.

If it is a choice of a smaller filter or nothing, at least do something like glue or tape a cardboard filler piece to the filter to make up the right size. The smaller filter area will behave like a filter that is already partially dirty, but you could use it temporarily.

Answer (score 2):

I ordered air filters that were the exact same size as the one I removed.  As I recall, the old filter fit perfectly. When I received the new filters, they were too small even though I took the numbers right off the old filter. Anyway, the size that I believe I actually do need is not in stock in any hardware store or big box store.  I had purchased three air filters, so I took one and cut 2" from one side, border included. (Very easy to cut) I took the part I cut and fit it onto one side of a filter, leaving no gaps, with heavy duty tape. It gave me the 1 1/2" I needed to fill out the enclosure for the grill.  It seems that this will work until I need to insert another filter.